# Optimizing svg using scour or any other optimizer in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, svg, optimization

I have been using scour and it works well. 
I would like to use it inside a Python app instead of a cli.
I would like the output to be the same as when I run the following command on CMD:

scour -i input.svg -o output.svgz --enable-viewboxing --enable-id-stripping \
  --enable-comment-stripping --shorten-ids --indent=none

Can't find any documentation how to call this function inside a python application

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: No, I need the output to be a file-like object and not a real file as I am uploading it to a CDN.

Comment: What is a file-like object? Why can't you post process the file into whatever you need?

Comment: a file-like class. Like Bytes-IO or String-IO. I Don't want the output to be an actual file. I want it to come out as a string so I could upload it directly to my AWS S3 Bucket. Uploading the actual file instead of a file that is stored in memory creates an unnecessary throughput in a very time critical environment.

Answer (score 4):

In the scour download, there is a `testscour.py` that you could use to see how you can access scour from within the code instead over the cli.

When I was finally solving my mostly similar scour problem, I did it like this:

```
from scour import scour
import re

with open(svg_file, 'r') as f
    svg = f.read() 

scour_options = scour.sanitizeOptions(options=None) # get a clean scour options object
scour_options.remove_metadata = True # change any option you like
clean_svg = scour.scourString(svg, options = scour_options) # use scour
```